# How to keep the value of dynamically created textfields with jquery on input type number click

Tags: jquery

How to keep the value of the text field while i create or add new text field.

```
<input type="number" name="item1" id="item1">
<hr />
<div id="item1box">

</div>

$('#item1').on('change',function(){

    $('#item1box').html('');
    var val = $(this).val();

    for (var i = 0; i < parseInt(val); i++){
        $('#item1box').prepend('<input type="text"><br />');
    }

});
```

Please have a look at this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fkbnm2y2/)

Note: i can add or delete field. by increasing or decreasing the input number.

Comment: there is nothing in your fiddle

Comment: Post code in question

Comment: I have updated the link @M.Nabeel

Comment: What exactly is issue?

Comment: Please have a look a the link @yogendarji
https://jsfiddle.net/fkbnm2y2/

Comment: Your fiddle seems to be working just fine, what exactly is your question?

Comment: I just need to keep the value when i add or delete new text field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var input = 0;
$('#item1').on('change', function() {

  var val = parseInt($(this).val());

  if (val >= 0) {

    if (input < val) {
      for (var i = input; i < parseInt(val); i++) {
        $('#item1box').append('<input type="text">');
      }
    } else {
      var allInput = $('#item1box input');
      allInput.each(function(index, ele) {
        debugger;
        if (index + 1 > val) {
          $(this).remove()
        }
      });
    }
    input = val;
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="item1" id="item1">
<hr />
<div id="item1box">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you,this is what i am looking for

Comment: @KhiradBanu Please mark answer if you find it useful

Comment: sure @yogen darji

Answer (score 1):

Well it is not a good practice to flush the complete html structure on every button click. There are better ways to do this.

However, here is a working fiddle as a starting point for you. Store the values in an Array to keep them save:

```js
$('#item1').on('change',function(){
 
    var values = [];
    
    for (var j = 0; j < $('input[type="text"]').length; j++){
     values.push($('input[type="text"]')[j].value);
    }
    values.push("");
    
    $('#item1box').html('');
    var val = $(this).val();
    
    for (var i = 0; i < parseInt(val); i++){
        $('#item1box').prepend('<input type="text" value="'+values[i]+'"><br />');
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="item1" id="item1">
<hr />
<div id="item1box">

</div>
```

Comment: Yes this is what i am looking for,but when we delete,it should delete the last record not random one.

Comment: That's why I wrote starting point. This should help you get going :-). Call console.log(values); to see what actually happens. The behaviour is not "random".

Comment: @KhiradBanu I personally doesn't recommend generating input element based on user input... it works okay when its 1,2,3,4... but try entering 32132313 into the input and see what happens

Comment: @halleron   Thank you,i will modify it further.

Comment: You are right,but user will not be allowed to put more then 20 @derrysan7

Comment: @KhiradBanu That is exactly my opinion. This is a very bad practice.

Comment: @KhiradBanu Please check below answer how I modified your code to  achieve your need.

Comment: @KhiradBanu if its only 20, you can change the input into a dropdown select

Comment: @hallleron,agreed with you,but i have to do this as its client requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You need the set the value when you create the textfields :

```
$('#item1box').prepend('<input type="text" value="' + val + '"><br />');
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/aL9m6omb/1/

Comment: Yes i can set it,but when i add new record,previous values are lost.i need to keep those values as well.i need dynamic values

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. What should be the output when you type, for example, 2, then 3 ?

Comment: Suppose i put in textbox1 "ABC" and then increase a number,then "ABC" should stay there. ABC is input value by user,so i can't set the value before.

Comment: Oh ok I see. Have a look to yogen darji's answer, I think it's what you need. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45214095/2611798